# How to return variable as array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to return a variable as an array like
`[ 'Google', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Apple', 'Oracle' ]`

But what I am getting is

```
Google
Facebook
Twitter
Barishal
Oracle
```

My code from setup() :

```
const stringOptions = axios.get('https://api.com').then(response 
 => {
        Object.keys(response.data.divisions).forEach(key => {
          var a = response.data.divisions[key].name
          console.log(a)
        })
    })
```

Comment: can u do ```axios.get(/*...*/).then(response => response.text()).then(data => console.log(data))``` and post the result here?

Comment: `return Object.keys(response.data.divisions).map((key) => response.data.divisions[key].name)`

Comment: @MichalLevý  Thanks a lot ! Have great day ... unfortunately I can't upvote since my reputation is near 0 :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) along with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

Try this **:**

```js
const divisions = {
  0: {
    name: 'Google'
  },
  1: {
    name: 'Facebook'
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Twitter'
  },
  3: {
    name: 'Barishal'
  },
  4: {
    name: 'Oracle'
  }
};

const res = Object.keys(divisions).map(key => divisions[key].name);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `Object.values` along with `Array.map()`

```js
const divisions = {
  0: {
    name: 'Google'
  },
  1: {
    name: 'Facebook'
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Twitter'
  },
  3: {
    name: 'Barishal'
  },
  4: {
    name: 'Oracle'
  }
};

const res = Object.values(divisions).map(division => division.name);

console.log(res);
```